# Installing a gem using saltstack with --user-install option

Tags: saltstack, gem

I want to replicate the following step of a deployment in saltstack, as a given user:

gem install --user-install bundler

I checked the [documentation](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.gem.html) and I was still unsure as to how to do this. I tried the following:

```
bundler-install:
  gem.installed:
    - user: username
    - name: bundler
```

And:

```
bundler-install:
  gem.installed:
    - user: username
    - name: bundler
    - gem_bin: gem install --user-install
```

And:

```
bundler-install:
  gem.installed:
    - user: username
    - gem_bin: gem install --user-install bundler
```

I guess I'm either doing it wrong or this isn't possible? Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I raised this a feature request/bug with saltstack:

https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/31821